# Error while attempt to connect to MySQL server from Delphi Windows application

Tags: mysql, delphi, absolute-path, firedac

I see that this has been a problem for many users, way back. I have read and tried most of the tips from these questions and answers without success. My connection works well on the development PC ("devPC"). The problem starts when I attempt to run it on a PC without Delphi installed. I think the problem is that it looks for `libmysql.dll` in the same directory as it was found on *devPC*. I have put this `libmysql.dll` in the same folder as the EXE file and also have the INI files for FireDac there. Anyone who knows how I get the the program to look for this .DLL at the right folder? Can I change this somewhere? The error message is:

> Loading driver MySQL ...
> Error: [FireDAC][Phys][MySQL]-314. Cannot load vendor library 
> [C:\Users\sjubu\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\Win32\Debug\libmysql.dll]. The specified module was not found.
> Hint: check it is in the PATH or application EXE directories, and has x86 bitness.

Comment: In your application, remove the path part of the .dll reference. Only refer to it by the actual file name `libmysql.dll`. If you wonder how that works, look for e.g. `dll search order` here at SO or in MS Windows docs. Dll's are first searched for in the directory of the calling exe.

Comment: You can deliver the DLL in question togehter  with your app or probably tell your users they have to install the MySQL (ODBC?) driver.

Comment: @TomBrunberg as i stated initially the .dll is in the same directory as the .exe so the dll search order does not seem to happen here. The path shown in the errormessage seem to be hardcoded/included into the exe, but not by me. It must be so since i moved only the exe and the dll to another computer and got this message. I'm stuck.

Comment: Show the code you run when it fails. Something with `LoadLibrary()`

Comment: To connect to mySQL, you are using FireDAC.Phys.TFDPhysDriverLink probably dropped on a datamodule. This component has a property VendorLib which specifies where the DLL is. You can leave it empty or - at runtime - build the complete path to libmysql.dll (Or read the path from an INI file). Read [Embarcadero documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FireDAC.Phys.TFDPhysDriverLink.VendorLib)

Comment: `@TomBrunberg`i use FireDac components from the Delphi palette and there is no source-code included for these components. It seems to me that it search for the `dll` in the initial folder of the `exe` and that this is a none-editable setting. I have change all project-directories in Delphi but nothing seems to help. I'm really stuck her.

Comment: `@fpiette` I have done that. I have read that docwiki. I have tried it all. The program works very well when it find the `dll` in the initial folder. But when i move it to another location it fails regardless of the `FireDac.TFDPhysMySQLDriverLink`. What to do then???

Comment: Look in the `.dfm` file then. If the reference there includes the path, remove it.

Comment: `@TomBrunberg`  It was not in `.dfm` either. I have searced the entire registry for the path to. There is a very frustrated programmer here no. I have run out of ideas.

Comment: SOLVED! `@TomBrunberg` `@fpiette` I don't know why, but it works. I moved the entire project to a new location. Changed all the directories in `project > options` and created a new *DataModule* with all the same components. Deleted the old *DataModule*, compiled it again and voila. It works. Happy happy.